# Execute program on Files in subDirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following architecture of files in a directory.

```
  Directory
     /A/abc.xyz
     /B/abc.xyz
     /C/abc.xyz
     /D/abc.xyz
     /E/abc.xyz
```

I want to execute a program on acb.xyz in each SubDirectory. Save Output files in different directory i.e. `Directory/processed` with the name of SubDirectory appended in the name of output files.
Can it be written in following way? Need corrections.

```
for i in `ls "Directory/"`
do
  program.pl $i/abc.xyz > processed/$i-abc.xyz
done
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with what you have written?

Comment: I got it, thank you @JohnKugelman. Putting  "" in input and output resolved the problem.

Comment: also you need to create directory `processed` before getting into loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for dir in Directory/*; do
    program.pl "$dir/abc.xyz" > "processed/${dir##*/}-abc.xyz"
done
```

The `${dir##*/}` part strips the leading directory names from `$dir`, so `Directory/A` becomes just `A`. I added quotes to ensure directory names with whitespace don't cause issue (a good habit, even if you know there are no spaces).

As an alternative to the string munging you could simplify this if you first change directory:

```
cd Directory

for dir in *; do
    program.pl "$dir/abc.xyz" > "processed/$dir-abc.xyz"
done
```